# Use lambda instead of itemgetter in python

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

Using sort is it possible to use a list [2, 5] or [2, 5, 6] or only [2], as an argument with itemgetter:

```
list_items = [2, 5, 6]
sorted(table_rows, key=itemgetter(*list_items), reverse=rev)
```

But I don't know how to have the same behavior with lambda function, only works with one element, with more it give me an error "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not list"

```
sorted(table_rows, key=lambda x:x(list_items), reverse=rev)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always directly construct the tuple:

```
sorted(table_rows, key=lambda x:tuple(x[i] for i in list_items), reverse=rev)
```

This is effectively what itemgetter() does.